# convert response curl function from string to an object or array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, api, curl

i have this function:

```
function sendXmlOverPost($url, $get_account_balance) {

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $get_account_balance);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // ask for results to be returned

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    print($result);
    return $result;
}

sendXmlOverPost($url, $get_account_balance);
```

I'm getting this answer :

> 300137EUR2.00SUCCESS

I would like to get an array or an object to have access only to the 2.00.

how could i do ? thanksss

Comment: What are the possible response types that the `$url` can give?

Comment: Is there not a parameter you can pass to the end point asking for the response to be sent in XML or JSON or something more useful and reliable than a blob of text

Comment: To parse a string like that reliably, you will need to know all the possible responses you might get in order to reliably seperate the specific parts

Answer (score 0):

If your string is consistently formatted as you show above you can use the [`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with the regex provided to get the `2.00`

```
$result = '300137EUR2.00SUCCESS'; // $result = sendXmlOverPost($url, $get_account_balance);
$pattern = '/(?<=EUR)\d\.(\d*)/'; 
preg_match($pattern, $result, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

[REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/td88kh/1)

- [Positive Lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<=EUR)` (start looking after the string 'EUR')
- `EUR` matches the characters EUR literally (case sensitive)
- `\d` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
- `\.` matches the character . literally
- 1st Capturing Group `(\d*)`
- `\d*` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
- `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

[EXAMPLE](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/58d9d11af9d420b2ee4509e724c39404e6c1d545)

If you expect that there may be more than one digit before the period change the regex to this:

```
(?<=EUR)(\d*)\.(\d*)
```